Error in Page Function in Apify Puppeteer (during Pagination)
I am trying to scrape news articles from this website using Apify Puppeteer crawler. I am trying to write a page-function in javascript to achieve the same but unable get it to work.
The webpage incorporates pagination so I am trying to navigate through all the relevant pages to extract all articles with publication date since '2024-08-15'.
The error says:
TypeError: context.enqueRequest is not a function

The details of the error is given below.
I am new to javascript, so any help is highly appreciated. The page-function code I was trying to write is given below.
Can someone please help me to fix the page-function in javascript to use it in Apify Puppeteer scraper.
async function pageFunction(context) {
    const { request, $, log, jQuery } = context;
    const results = [];
    const url = context.request['url'];
    const pageopt = 'home';
    const pageoption = context.customData.pageopt;
    
    
    //Define startDate
    const startDate = new Date('2024-08-15');
    
    //Get the page object from the context
    const { page } = context;
    
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" });
    const litags = null;
    
    if ( pageoption === 'True') {
        try {
            await page.waitForSelector('ul.bwNewsList li');
            liTags = await page.$$('ul.bwNewsList li');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('An error occurred: ', error);
        }
    }
    else {
        try {
            await page.waitForSelector('ul.bwNewsList li');
            liTags = await page.$$('ul.bwNewsList li');
        } catch(error) {
            console.error('An error occurred: ', error);
        }
    }
    
    const urls = [];
    let date = null;
    
    for (let li of liTags) {
        date = new Date(await li.$eval('time', el => el.getAttribute('datetime')));
        
        const aTag = await li.$('a');
        const href = aTag ? await (await aTag.getProperty('href')).jsonValue() : null;
        
        if (date >= startDate) {
            urls.push(href);
        }
    }
    
    console.log(date)
    console.log(startDate)
    
    if (date >= startDate) {
        const nxthref = await page.$eval('div.pagingNext a', element => element.href);
        console.log(nxthref);
        context.customData.pageopt = 'False';
        await context.enqueRequest({ 'url' : nxthref});
    }
    
    for (let url of urls) {
        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: " domcontentloaded" });
        
        let title = await page.$eval('title', el => el.textContent.replace(/[\r\n\s]+/g, " ") );
        const unique_article = url.concat(title);
        
        // Generate the hash of the title
        const titleHash = await page.evaluate(async (unique_article) => {
            const encoder = new TextEncoder();
            const data = encoder.encode(unique_article);
            const hash = await window.crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', data);
            const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hash) );
            return hashArray.map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('');
        }, unique_article);
        
        const pgdate = new Date(await page.$eval('div.bw-release-timestamp time', el => el.getAttribute('datetime')));
        const divs = await page.$$('p');
        let text = '';
        for (let div of divs) {
            text += await page.evaluate(el => el.textContent, div);
        }
        text = text.replace(/[\r\n\s]+/g, " ");
        
        results.push({
            'article_id': titleHash,
            'url': url,
            'title': title,
            'content': text,
            'published_date': pgdate,
            'publisher': 'BW'
        });
    }
    
    return results;
}

The error in Apify is:
ERROR PuppeteerCrawler: Request failed and reached maximum retries. TypeError: context.enqueRequest is not a function
    at CrawlerSetup.pageFunction [as evaledPageFunction] (evalmachine.<anonymous>:57:23)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async wrap (/home/myuser/node_modules/@apify/timeout/cjs/index.cjs:54:21)

Can someone please help.

what's the point of using Apify for this use-case?, I would even ask what's the point of using apify at all...
